# Highlight specific points on a surface chart in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I was wondering if its possible to highlight a series of x,y,z points on a surface chart in excel, similar to what ive done manually in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible, and there isn't really a workaround.

You can try using 3d graphing sheets like [this](http://www.doka.ch/Excel3Dscatterplot.htm) but it won't make a surface plot. You may be out of luck.

Comment: +1 for the interesting link, but there IS a workaround (just not using the graph tools), and that would be to use geometrical figures, that are available in all recent Excel versions.

Comment: I suppose you could create VBA to generate a 3d surface chart automatically using shapes, but that solution is worse than the original problem!

Comment: what I meant was for the OP to *manually* place a small filled circle in the position. And yes, the solution *you* said is worse. Barring use of other tools such as Gnuplot or Matplotlib I don't see how else to do this.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that would actually be a very clever solution @Doktoro! Talk about me suggesting an overengineered solution!

Comment: @jmac Thanks for the link + Doktoro Reichard thanks for the suggestion of using geometrical figures, i'll see which i can get to work.

Comment: Using geometrical figures (in the sense of creating a program to map out 3d data using perspective to mimic the surface chart) is probably not realistic. It would be far easier to create a program to guesstimate where to plot the red dots you have there within the chart area if you are inclined to go the extra mile. At any rate, best of luck.